# Как упаковывают данные в Go?

Tags: golang, структуры-данных

Начал изучать Go после php и решил в целях обучения написать небольшую программку, которая давно была нужна. Натолкнулся на одну проблему. Например в php, если мне нужен некоторый пакет данных, я пишу:

```
$array = array(
    'foo'   => null,
    'bar'   => null,
);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {...}
```

И в этом цикле я могу прочитать нужные данные из нужного места и как-то отреагировать на них.

Не пойму как это же сделать в Go
Можно конечно сделать все линейно, обычным присваиванием, но хочется чтобы код выглядел симпатичней и понятней для дальнейшего прочтения и использования.

```
Пишу вот так:

        type pluginSettings struct {
            app string
            name string
            version string
            vendor string
            frontend bool
            settings bool
        }
```

А как потом перебрать и присвоить данным их значения? У меня есть конфигурационный текстовый файл, в котором хранятся настройки с аналогичными именами. Но конфиг большой и для этой части кода нужна только его часть, которая читается с определенной логикой и приоритетами. Просто так считать часть конфига нельзя. Нужно именно перебирать данные.

Answer (score 1):

Приравнивать структуры к ассоциативным массивам в *PHP* нельзя.
Последние больше похожи на `map` в *Go*, которые вы
вполне можете использовать тут.

Технически, по полям структуры пройтись можно с помощью
`reflect`, но тут это явный перебор.  Тем более, что одна из
[*Go*-поговорок](https://go-proverbs.github.io/)
явно гласит, что «*reflection is never clear*».

Вообще, конфигурацию лучше декодировать в структуры готовыми средствами,
типа
[`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json).
Или вообще пользоваться переменными окружения и флагами.